# saved multiple ggplots in a folder by R

Tags: r, pdf, ggplot2

I have the following data and code

```
data <- data.frame(trt = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A"), group = c("G1", "G1", "G1", "G1", "G1", "G2", "G2", "G2", "G2", "G2"), value = c(6.4, 7.2, 6.5, 6.6, 6.2, 7.2, 8.5, 7.3, 7.1, 6.9))

for(i in c(1:2)) {
  savePDFPath <- paste("/Path/Plot/G", i, ".pdf", sep = "")
  pdf(file = savePDFPath)
  dd <- subset(data, group == paste("G", i, sep = ""))
  ggplot(dd, aes(trt, value)) + geom_boxplot()
  dev.off()
}
```

After I execute this code, 2 pdf files are saved in the folder. Nevertheless, I cannot open the files. It shows `the file Gx.pdf could not be opened. What goes wrong in my code? Thank you.

- It works fine if I don't wrap the code in a for loop.

Comment: Your ggplot code will only produce an empty plot as you haven't added any geoms.

Comment: Have you verified that each individual plot works, before trying to save them to PDF? Please try to provide a reproducible example (with example data) that people can try themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `ggsave()` to save the plot as pdf. I've tried the following code and it works.

```
for(i in c(1:2)) {
  savePDFPath <- paste("/Path/Plot/G", i, ".pdf", sep = "")
  dd <- subset(data, group == paste("G", i, sep = ""))
  ggplot(dd, aes(trt, value)) + geom_boxplot()
  ggsave(savePDFPath)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure why the error is occurring but I'm able to fix it by explicitly printing the plot:

```
for(i in c(1:2)) {
    savePDFPath <- paste("Plots/G", i, ".pdf", sep = "")
    pdf(file = savePDFPath)
    dd <- subset(data, group == paste("G", i, sep = ""))
    p <- ggplot(dd, aes(trt, value)) + geom_boxplot()
    print(p)
    dev.off()
}
```